Definition of Coordinates in Hopkins' "On the Diffraction Theory of Optical Images"
I am reading "On the Diffraction Theory of Optical Images" by Hopkins. BTW, This is the paper from which most of industrial lithography modeling systems are built on (Hopkins formulation and SOCS). In the paper, the author proposes an imaging system with a plane of effective source, an object plane, an entrance pupil, an exit pupil and a plane of imaging. Then the author discusses coordinates. It is suggested in the paper that given $\left(\xi, \eta\right)$ as the geometrical distance in the object, $k$ be the wave number in vacuum, $N$ as the refractive index and $\alpha$ as the angle of intersection with a sphere, the coordinates used in mathematical formulation is $\left(u,v\right)$, where $u = k \left(N \sin \alpha\right) \xi$ and $v = k \left(N \sin \alpha\right) \eta$. What is the so-called geometrical distance, and what is the meaning of this transformation?
Further, the only references I have for partial coherence are two papers, namely, "The Concept of Partial Coherence in Optics" and "On the Diffraction Theory of Optical Images". I found these papers are hard to read in that a lot of technical constructions are omitted. What's more, to be able to implement numerical code, more details need to be revealed. Is there a text book on optics that include full technical construction of the work from Hopkins?
